# Constructing half open intervals from open intervals

Tags: measure-theory

Is there a way to construct [-$\infty$,a) from countable unions/intersections of intervals of the form (a,b) or their complements?

Comment: If base space is $[-\infty,+\infty)$ , then  yes!

Comment: Ah good! I was uncertain if I was aiming to get somewhere that couldn't be reached! I think I have it now so thank you for your encouragement! :)